# Finite Elements or Finite Difference for the Heat Equation, Dissipates the Entropy?

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods, finite-differences, finite-element-method

Given an initial density $\rho_0$ on $\Omega\subset \mathbb{R}^d$, it is well known that the Heat Equation

$$ \partial_t \rho(t)=\Delta\rho(t),~~~~~~~\rho(0)=\rho_0, ~~~~~(1)$$

dissipates the entropy $H$, defined (for a density $f$) as $H(f):=\int f\log f $, i.e $H(\rho(t))$ is decreasing as $t$ increases.

The question is : Suppose you  solve $(1)$ via finite elements or finite difference, would this approximate solution also dissipate entropy (at every discrete time point)?

Comment: The heat equation is usually for temperature, right? $$\partial_t T = \Delta T. $$
How do you relate $f$ and $\rho$? By integration over the particle velocities? $$\rho(\boldsymbol{x}) = \int_{\mathbb{R}^3} f(\boldsymbol{x} , \boldsymbol{c} ) \mathrm d \boldsymbol{c} $$

Comment: I was just using $f$ as a dummy variable for the definition of the entropy.

Comment: Okay, but if you solve the PDE for $\rho$ you have to come up with a way to relate this to the entropy / H-function $H$ to be able to make any statements on this?

Comment: Solve the PDE - plug in the solution to $H$, along the time increments, is $H$ decreasing. Fix a time increment $\delta t$ , say $\rho^n$ is the solution at time $\delta t n$, then is $H(\rho^n)< H(\rho^m)$ for $n>m$.

Comment: @PDEmethods Here you can find some experiments: https://www.intlpress.com/site/pub/files/_fulltext/journals/cms/2017/0015/0001/CMS-2017-0015-0001-a002.pdf

Comment: @PierreCarre obrigado ! :)